# 3d modeling in cuda (raytracing pre-stage)

Tags: opengl, cuda, raytracing, optix

I'm trying to implement a simple raytracing code using CUDA.

**I'm stuck at the modeling part**. im trying to figure out how to model a 3d space with objects (start with a simple 3d space containing a 3d cube in the middle).

i've read about hybrid projects with openGL and CUDA but those articles were too general - and 
as i said i am new at this.

are there any libraries/code for implementing such a 3d model?

Comment: I would work on that accept rage. Just sayin'

Comment: got it datenwolf, thx. im new too stackof too :)

Comment: Do you need to use CUDA at this stage?  I would recommend that you write a ray tracer in the programming language you're most proficient in.  After you have a working ray tracer, then create a CUDA version.

Comment: actually no, i dont have to do the 3d model in CUDA, but i do need the threads running in CUDA later (for the raytracing) to use the objects created in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do ray tracing in CUDA, take a look at NVIDIA's [OptiX](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optix.html), which is an API for GPU-accelerated ray tracing. There are several [example](http://developer.nvidia.com/optix-interactive-examples) codes in the [SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/optix-download) ranging from simple to sophisticated. They will demonstrate how to model 3D objects in your renderer.

On the other hand, if you're new to both CUDA and ray tracing, you probably don't want to tackle both at once :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I downloaded OptiX, installed and ran the samples. 
I am having trouble understanding where is the work environment, how to compile the code, or even which kind of files are there?
I read the tutorial and programming guide.
Do you have any examples or tutorials?

Comment: well, eventually i used **Blender** to model the room to *.obj files and then i used __trier's raytracing tutorial__ (search google) information to read the *.obj files into openGL code